# Что означает ошибка opencv error assertion failed (p[-1] <= 2) и как с ней бороться?

Tags: c++, opencv, matlab, обработка-изображений

Пытаюсь перевести код матлаба на плюсы, с использованием библиотеки OpenCV.

На нижеприведенной строчке:

```
resize(sig_temp, sig_temp, \
Size(sig_temp.size[0] / 2 + sig_temp.size[0] % 2, \
sig_temp.size[1] / 2 + sig_temp.size[1] % 2));
```

Программа валится с ошибкой:

```
opencv error assertion failed (p[-1] <= 2) in cv::Matsize::operator()
```

Предыдущие ошибки `(dims<=2,top/bottom/right/left>=0)` были довольно очевидны, т.к. из них было ясно, что размерностей должно быть не больше двух, границы изображения должны быть неотрицательными. Тут же я не понимаю, что значит p[-1] и почему оно должно быть не больше двух (но догадываюсь, что здесь что-то опять связано со слоями).

`sig_temp` -- трехканальная матрица Mat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка, скорее всего, вызвана тем, что размерность Матрицы (не число ее каналов) больше 2х. Matsize возвращает целочисленный массив и p[-1] скорее всего означает размер этого массива.